# Android Bootloader concepts for developers - in-depth explanation request

Tags: android, bootloader

Can sombody provide me some in-depth sources to read about locked bootloaders?

What I would like to understand mainly is the concept which won't let you overwrite the locked bootloader with another one. I think once you have the hardware in your hands you can write (flash) the whole memory if it's writable.

I will provide an example to give a starting point. I've stumbled upon this conceptional problem when users trying to change the rom on LG G Pad 8.3. It has two versions:
V500 with LG's mod on Android 4.2.2.
V510 with Stock Android 4.4 (Google play edition)

The hardware in those devices are the same, the difference is in the software. Why one can't just mirror the whole V510 contents (partitions, data, boot, etc...) on a V500?

I'm a developer, so I'd really like to understand the concept in depth.

Thanks for any help

Comment: more information about on topic - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust